# Cauchy's residue theorem for ratio of two polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I am considering to apply the residue theorem to the ratio $P(x)/Q(x)$ of two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$. One condition to do this is that the degrees of the two polynomials satisfy $\deg P(x)+2\leq \deg Q(x)$.

My question is: what can I do when $\deg P(x)$ does not satisfy this condition? Are there more general formulations of the theorem that can still be applied?

Comment: Hang on, in what context are you applying the residue theorem? You need to mention that, or the condition may really be unnecessary.

Comment: @chappers You're absolutely correct. I presume the OP is looking at a contour that extends in a limit to infinity.

Comment: I am looking at inverting a function of a single complex variable that is rational and analytic in a neighborhood of the origin. The integral is over the unit circle. I know the roots of the polynomials to be real.